# Can someone explain why Sencha Toolbar CSS is not working for Chrome?

Tags: css, firebug, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a top docked toolbar, and I used firebug to inspect the element to find the css class, which was:

```
  .x-toolbar-dark.x-docked-top 
  {
      border-bottom-color: #000000;
  }
```

I changed this to:

```
  .x-toolbar-dark.x-docked-top 
  {
     border-bottom-color: #000000;
     background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

Now I see the toolbar as transparent in Firefox, but in chrome it still has the default background color (blue).  Why does this happen?  Maybe I don't need to use this technique here, but there are definitely instances where I need to find a very specific css class using firebug.  Any help or information?

Note: I tried using the Cls attribute of the toolbar with the same result.

Comment: too little information for me - jsfiddle?

Comment: @Horen  I have never used it before, but I'll try to put it up now.

Comment: Here it is:  I used the 'cls' attribute for styling - Works for firefox on jsfiddle but not chrome.  However, you can also use the .x-toolbar-dark.x-docked-top class above and see it not work for yourself if you'd like: http://jsfiddle.net/sd1212/awHkT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome the background image (it's a gradient) works meanwhile in Firefox it is ignored.

So all you have to do is set the background-image and the background-color of `.x-toolbar-dark` like this:

```
.x-toolbar-dark{
   background-image: none;   
   background-color: transparent;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awHkT/1/

Comment: That's very interesting (it worked).  How did you know that the background image in Firefox was ignored?

Comment: I've tried this to my code - but i still can't make my toolbar transparent. i can see in firebug that my toolbar has applied the css rules. but still i cannot "see through" the toolbar....

Answer (score 0):

Sencha is for webkit browser, so it's CSS is made for webkit browsers like Chrome or Safari. So this kind or problem must be because there's a CSS rule with a -webkit prefix that is hence only applied on webkit browsers and ignored in firefox.

But anyway, toolbars have a gradient background, so if you want to override it you will need to do like so :

```
background-image: none;
background-color: transparent;
```

**Two last thing**

- It's bad practice to override Sencha's CSS. Use the the `cls` config on you toolbar to assign it a CSS class and then use this class to style your toolbar.
- Don't test you app with Firefox, but with Chrome of Safari.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Can you creating a custom theme installing SASS and Compass. The instructions for installing SASS and Compass vary slightly for Mac and Windows users. Mac users will need to open the Terminal application and type the following:

```
i. sudo gem install haml
ii. sudo gem install compass
```

You will need to authenticate with your username and password to complete the install.
Windows users need to open the command line and type the following:

```
i. gem install haml
ii. gem install compass
```

**Installing Ruby**

Mac users get a break, since Ruby is already installed on OSX by default. Windows users should download the Ruby installer from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org).

Once the installation is complete, we are ready to set up our folders and begin using SASS and Compass.

**Creating your custom theme**

The next thing you need to do is create your own theme SCSS file. Locate the sencha-touch.scss file in ../lib/resources/sass, and make a copy of the file. Rename the new copy of the file to myTheme.scss.

Now, you need to tell the index to look for your new theme. Using your previous example files, open your index.html file, and locate the line that says the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
```

Change the sencha-touch.css stylesheet reference in your index.html file to point to myTheme.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/resources/css/myTheme.css" type="text/css">
```

**SCSS and CSS**

Notice that you are currently including a stylesheet from the css folder, called sencha-touch.css, and you have a matching file in the scss folder, called sencha-touch.scss. When the SCSS files are compiled, it creates a new file in your css folder. This new file will have a suffix of .css instead of .scss.

.scss is the file extension for SASS files. SCSS is short for Sassy CSS.

Now that you have your paths set up, let's take a look at the theme file copy we made. Open your myTheme.scss file. You should see the following:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
@includesencha-panel;
@includesencha-buttons;
@includesencha-sheet;
@includesencha-picker;
@includesencha-tabs;
@includesencha-toolbar;
@includesencha-toolbar-forms;
@includesencha-carousel;
@includesencha-indexbar;
@includesencha-list;
@includesencha-list-paging;
@includesencha-list-pullrefresh;
@includesencha-layout;
@includesencha-form;
@includesencha-msgbox;
@includesencha-loading-spinner;
```

This code grabs all of the default Sencha Touch theme files and compiles them into a new CSS file located in the css folder. If you open up the sencha-touch.css file in the ../lib/resources/css folder, you will see the compressed CSS file you were previously using. This file is pretty huge, but it's all created from the basic commands.

The best part is that you can now change the entire color scheme of the application with a single line of code.

**Base color**

One of the key variables in the Sencha Touch theme is `$base_color`. This colour and its variations are used throughout the entire theme. To see what we mean, you change the colour of your theme adding the following to the top of your myTheme.scss file (**above all the other text**):

```
$base_color: #d1d3d4; //for example, color gray
```

Next, you need to re-compile the SASS file to create your stylesheet. From the command line, you need to change into the sass folder where your myTheme.scss file lives. Once you are in the folder, type the following into the command line and hit Enter:

```
compass compile
```

And have fun :), this will update your myTheme.css file with the new `$base_color` value. Reload the page in Safari or FF or anywhere, and you should see a new gray look to your application.

And look at this in http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/styling-user-interface-sencha-touch-application

**I hope this helps. :)**

Comment: This is a great answer but not the this question which if you read it again is 'Can someone explain why Sencha Toolbar CSS is not working for Chrome?'. So first, your answer doesn't actually answer the question and second. You could just have provided this link http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/styling-user-interface-sencha-touch-application which is a copy/paste of your answer (or vice versa)

Comment: Sorry is a great answer for change color toolbar.